# Change size of canvas by click

Tags: c++, graphics, 2d, vcl, borland-c++

There is a circle made with the help of canvas method `MainForm -> Canvas -> Ellipse(350,100,550,300)`. The question is to change size of canvas by clicking "+" or "-" buttons. Are there any methods?

Comment: Borland C++!? Havent seen that for years :)

Comment: @ViktorSehr it's "modern" education in our country:)

Comment: Which country is that?

Comment: @ViktorSehr Ukraine, but I think that it is so in most post-USSR countries:)

Comment: @ViktorSehr yep in central and eastern Europe (not only former CCCP/USSR but also post RVHP) is Borland/Embarcadero still alive even when the prices are so sky-high (it was a clever marketing from Borland that most technical schools got the compilers and IDE's for free). but luckily the old Turbo C++ or Pascal is not the compiler in most cases anymore... :)

Comment: @DNilla by Canvas did you mean size of Ellipse or really the Canvas (Form size) ?

Answer (score 0):

for resizing ellipse:

1. **create some global or Form member variables:**

   - `int x0=350,y0=100,x1=550,y1=300;`
   - this holds the ellipse parameters
2. **create some draw function (member to form or not)**

   - for example:

     ```
     void draw(TCanvas *scr)
      {
      scr->Pen->Color=clWhite;
      scr->Brush->Color=clBlack;
      scr->FillRect(TRect(0,0,MainForm->ClientWidth,MainForm->ClientHeight));
      scr->Brush->Color=clBlue;
      scr->Ellipse(x0,y0,x1,y1);
      }
     ```
   - create events on resize and on paint for the main form and add draw(Canvas); call in booth
   - that will repaint your form when needed
3. **create on (mouse) click event**

   - inside you have calling variables `X,Y,Shift` holding mouse state
   - so simply add this to it
   - `x1=X; y1=Y; draw(Canvas);`

That is all ... hope I did not make some typo (wrote from memory directly here)

If you need to resize the form then:

- instead of `x1=X, y1=Y;` do
- `ClientWidth=X+32; ClientHeight=Y+32;`
- or use `SetBounds(Left,Top,X+32,Y+32);`
- the `+32` is resize area to ensure you can also enlarging ...

**[edit1] did miss the +/- buttons (I assumed mouse resize) so here are the buttons**

1. create on + button click event:

   - leave the existing code as is and add to the event code this

     ```
     int cx=(x0+x1)>>1,ax=(x1-cx); ax+=16; x0=cx-ax; x1=cx+ax;
     int cy=(y0+y1)>>1,ay=(y1+cy); ay+=16; y0=cy-ay; y1=cy+ay; draw(Canvas);
     ```
   - that will enlarge booth semi-axises by 16 on each click
2. create on - button click event:

   - code is similar to +

     ```
     int cx=(x0+x1)>>1,ax=(x1-cx); ax-=16; if (ax<1) ax=1; x0=cx-ax; x1=cx+ax;
     int cy=(y0+y1)>>1,ay=(y1+cy); ay-=16; if (ay<1) ay=1; y0=cy-ay; y1=cy+ay; draw(Canvas);
     ```
   - that will shrink booth semi-axises by 16 on each click and stop on size 1

if you need the form to resize  then adapt the above code ... like in the on mouse event example